# Cannot add layers to map canvas from spatial queries against a PostGIS database connection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I am having trouble adding the results of spatial queries against a PostGIS connection to the map canvas in QGIS.

GIVEN:

- I am able to add the results of queries against my PostgreSQL/PostGIS connection -- as long as the queries do not contain any spatial statements (e.g. ST_Union, ST_Buffer, etc.)
- The "Execute SQL" dialog DOES return the correct results of the spatial query but when I load the layer to the map, there is an error ("Unavailable layer")
- QGIS version = 3.30.3
- PostGIS_version() =  3.2 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1

I've already tried making sure to include a unique key column in my query - as I thought that maybe it would be a requirement for the layer to display. This is my query:

```sql
SELECT 1 as id, ST_Union(ST_Buffer(1609*20))
FROM highways
WHERE name = 'US Route 1' AND state = 'MD';
```

This is what the added QueryLayer looks like when I attempt to add it:

[image: screenshot of QGIS Layers panel showing issue with adding the query result to the map]

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind - it seemed that the QGIS query interface does not like the trailing `;`.

Removing the semi-colon seems to resolve the issue.